# Constraints Foregin Key allows null?

Tags: mysql

I have these two tables:

```
 Table1
ID,int(Key) not null
Name,nvarchar not null

Table2
MyCode, int(key) not null
Year, int(key) not null
ExternalCode,int(Fkey) null
```

Constraints

```
ALTER TABLE "Table2" WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT"FK_Table2_Table1_ExternalCode" CHECK ([ExternalCode] IS NOT NULL) REFERENCES [Table1] (ID) 
ALTER TABLE "Table2" CHECK CONSTRAINT "FK_Table2_Table1_ExternalCode";
```

SQL server reports syntax error in REFERENCES, how can I create the constraint? Or rather, is it possible to insert a costraint on a foreign key if my key (ExternalCode) is nullable?

Edit...
The Table2 index is MyCode,year,ExternalCode, in certain conditions decided by a configuration parameter from the application, Table1 can be empty and in no way can a record be written to it and therefore ExternalCode can be null in those cases, in other cases or when Table1 has records (why not base as soon as I modify that condition a record is written on Table1)

Comment: How can your ExternalCode column be null if it is referencing to a not null column. Can you please provide more context?

Comment: I modify this answer